# cl.exe - vs2017, native app build on Windows 7, not run under Windows XP

Tags: windows, visual-studio

A simple hello world app,

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello\n");
}
```

build with command, on Windows 7 32-bit:

```
cl main.c /o main.exe
```

When run under Windows XP (32 bit) cause:

```
Not a valid win32 application.
```

Why such a case ?

Comment: It's much like any game system or other operating system. You can have later builds still run older builds, but not the other way around without special customization because the older builds don't recognize the newer build technology.

Comment: What do you mean by `special customization` , this is just a barebone program.

Comment: It was built on a Windows 7 machine, meaning there is certain underlying code through the compiler that is unknown to the Windows XP machine.

Comment: You have to use the special Platform Toolset if you want to target Windows XP. This is explained in the manual that came with your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can run versions of app build for **XP** in **Windows 7**, but not the vice versa. Just like most games, the newer version of the apps do not run in older version of windows. Apps for **Win 7** or **Win 10** does not run in **XP**

Comment: Not alike, the compatibility does not state that: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-vs

Comment: You maybe able to specify the minimum version of compatibility, just like in while developing an android app, you got to specify the minimum version